# Openpyxl huge ram consumption on save plus it takes a lot of time to save a file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to automate the generation some reports. My first aproach was to read the csv file with the updated data and then generate the whole Excel with pivot tables using pandas.

This was not the best idea due the reports complexity so I decided I would use a base template and dump the processed data inside a sheet on a new file based on the template. This aproach worked well, except that it takes too much resources (RAM and time), but this was not a problem till today when I got a "Memmory Error".

After searching for a solution I discovered the amount of data I was dumping and the Template itself were the root cause of the problem.

Here's a simplified aproach of what I'm currently doing:

```
# Load the data
data = pd.read_csv(data_path)

# Do some processing to agregate data
processed_data = process_data(data)

# Open the template
wb = load_workbook(template_path, keep_vba=True)

# Copy to the template the processed data
processed_data_rows = dataframe_to_rows(processed_data, index=False)

ws = self.wb['data']
        for r_idx, row in enumerate(processed_data_rows, 1):
            for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
                if value is None:
                    ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value='')
                else:
                    ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

# Save the data to the new file
wb.save(path)
```

In my search I found that I could use some read/write optimizations with read_only and write_only, but I could't find a way to copy the sheets from the loaded template to the Excel report I'm creating in the new file.

Any Ideas on how to solve this Issue?

PS: The loaded csv it's about 30k rows and 140 columns.

Edit: The output file size is about 12Mb (not even close to the 1.80~2.3Gb the script uses)

Comment: Do you have lxml installed? This should resolve any memoy errors when writing.

Comment: No I didn't, after installing it the RAM usage went to 1.85Gb during the save process, then after some minutes it crashed: "SystemError: <cyfunction Element at 0x07EBA2A0> returned NULL without setting an error"
Full trace here: https://pastebin.com/gepzWgXV

Comment: That's an lxml / Cython exception which you'll have to report to lxml. Memory use with lxml installed should be fairly constant when writing. 30k * 140 is a reasonable size but not that big. Can you see how things perform without having to use the template?

Comment: The usage of the template itself it's not a problem (it's a 4Mb xlsm file), the problem is to save it (no matter if I add the 30k*140 data or not). wb.save is the function that's giving me this pain (maybe cause I'm new in python).

Comment: Yes you need lxml but size does matter with openpyxl you can easily reach a limit, keeping in mind that xlsx is a compressed version of a larger xls

Comment: Using the template forces openpyxl to keep all cells in memory. However, with lxml it won't also create an ElementTree when writing each worksheet. Not much use, however, until the bug you're seeing is fixed.

Comment: So there's nothing I can really do? There's no other way? I really need to complete this task for my work.

Comment: Without the files it's difficult to be sure but I suspect that the lxml/Cython error may be related to the platform you're working on (32-bit Windows). It might be an idea to try a different platform. Otherwise you will need more memory and probably a 64-bit Python.

Comment: So I switched to python x64 (I had been using x32 without knowing) and the crash stop. The report is generated but now the script RAM usage rises up to 3.5Gb! I know the xlsm is a zip of other files but really?
I can't publish the template file due company policy (I could get in trouble if they find, the kind of trouble that cost mony). But there's nothing special about these files, just some sheets (2 hidden, and less than 10 in total), a couple of pivot tables, and some macros.


Edit:
The output file's size is 9Mb and Excel did use 5Gb to open it! WTF? Could I be doing something wrong?